# Custom Counter Tag/Bubble

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create a counter of hashtags for a personal website. I would like to present something similar to twitter, fb kind of counter bubble.

what is the best way to create that? CSS?jQuery?
I get the hashtags and its count from the database. Currently I display it under as one single

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: is it a static counter or does it need to pop out in an animated fashion?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it depends on the technology you're using for your web app.

You're talking about adding a simple bit of text, with some decoration around it.  There are dozens or hundreds of ways to do this, using every web technology under the sun.

You'll probably get better results if you try something using whatever tech your project is already using, then post questions when you have problems.

Comment: may be I should have explained little bit more myself. I can show the counter in a different box, color it , border it, shade it etc using CSS. However, I am not able to get the arrow like the way it comes on a bubble comment or twitter like count box.

Comment: this helped me. using css3 to accomplish what I wanted. http://jonrohan.me/guide/css/creating-triangles-in-css/